# cat a file to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, cat

Assuming the name of my script is `myscript.sh` and my current directory is `/Users/scripts/` I'm trying to do the following:

```
localScript=$(cat ./myscript.sh)
```

I get the following error:

```
#!/bin/sh not found
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this, but I assume its not working because `$()` is creating a subshell that has a different pwd and thus cannot find my file.

I've also tried using various combinations of `pwd` but I'm having trouble with this method as well.

Comment: Your one line here is fine. The error is elsewhere. Do you run localScript=$(cat ./myscript.sh) in a terminal ? From a script ? Are you certain it's the `localScript=$(cat ./myscript.sh)` that throws this error ? $() will have the same working directory as your run it in.

Comment: Run `type cat` and see what you get.

Comment: @nos I've tried doing this exact same variable assignment from the terminal and also by including it in my script and running the script from the terminal.

Comment: @anubhava I get `cat is /bin/cat`

Comment: Did you create this script file on Windows? That can cause this problem.

Comment: @RobinGreen nope this script was created in OSX using bash

Comment: Can you try: `bash -c 'localScript=$(cat ./myscript.sh)'`

Comment: @inquisitor what, you used echo to create the file? ;) I was talking about the text editor you used to create the file.

Comment: @RobinGreen ahh.. well I used macvim

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57502/read-entire-file-into-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OSX I've done the following:

```
$ vim test.sh
```

and typed in the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
localScript=$(cat ./test.sh)
echo $localScript
```

and then,

```
 $ chmod +x test.sh
 $ ./test.sh
```

which gives the following output:

```
#!/bin/sh localScript=$(cat ./test.sh) echo $localScript
```

Maybe the above will help you spot your error.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the difference is, but thanks!

Comment: Me neither, but sometimes it just helps to retry :-)